# How to get a products file attachments

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using a module called Intellimage_Attachs, what I want to do is get the files that I have attached to a product, how would I do this?

Have tried things like:

`$product->getAttachs();
$product->getDownloadable();`

But no luck any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will work or not, But I checked your extension and it is creating an additional attribute called samples_title

try this way

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
$product->setTypeInstance(Mage::getModel('attachs/product_type', $typeInstance), true);

$samples = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSamples($product);

foreach ($samples as $_link)
{
    print_r($_link);
}
```

Comment: found the title, literally just a string

Comment: edited my answer, it should work now

Comment: `<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/media/downloadable/files/samples".$_link->getData('sample_file')."'>Here </a>";` doesnt work

Comment: get 404 not found

Comment: but the file is there in the file system on ftp

Comment: <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('downloadable/download/sample', array('sample_id' => $_link->getId())); ?>"><?php echo ($_link->getTitle()); ?></a> try this way

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try bellow functions

```
$samples = product->getTypeInstance(Mage::getModel('attachs/product_type', $typeInstance), true);
        foreach ($samples as $item) {

            $file = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->getFilePath(
                Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sample::getBasePath(), $item->getSampleFile()
            );
        }
```

Comment: use my answer to fix your own for reference if someone else looks @ this question

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this myself with help from Abdul;

```
        $get_downloads = Mage::getModel('downloadable/product_type');
        $get_downloads->setProduct($product);
        $downloads = $get_downloads->getSamples();

        foreach ($downloads as $download) {

            $file = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->getFilePath(
                Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sample::getBasePath(), $download->getSampleFile()
            );


        }
```

Comment: you can up-vote if that work for you