# Extending the Magento XML-RPC API

Tags: api, layered-navigation, xmlrpc

Is it possible to extend the Magento XML-RPC API To Retrieve a list of attributes used in layered navigation, or is this a limitation of this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New API can be introduced. Take `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api::items()` as a starting point.
It returns the following:

```
...
result[] = array(
    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
    'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
    'type' => $attribute->getFrontendInput(),
    'required' => $attribute->getIsRequired(),
    'scope' => $scope
);
...
```

Modify this code to check if current attribute is filterable and return value of this field:

```
...
if ($attribute->getIsFilterable()) {
    $result[] = array(
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
        'type' => $attribute->getFrontendInput(),
        'required' => $attribute->getIsRequired(),
        'is_filterable' => $attribute->getIsFilterable(),
        'scope' => $scope
    );
}
...
```

You can check how to add new custom API in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89181/how-to-upload-a-file-attachment-to-custom-product-attribute-using-magento-soap/89741#89741). To enable XML RPC only *api.xml* and *Api.php* files should be created (no *wsdl.xml* or *V2.php* needed).

Then perform request to your new API like you would to [product attributes list API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.list.html).

Comment: Unbelievable - I didn't realise Magento could be so simple - thank you!