# How can I update special prices in magento via API?

Tags: api, soap-api-v2, special-price

I try this scrpit to update special prices. The update is slowly. Is it possible to update any item in one request? In this issue I make request for every item.

## SOAP V2

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductSetSpecialPrice($sessionId, '2', '77.5', '2012-03-29 12:30:51', '2012-04-29 12:30:51');
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In SOAP V2 this is not possible without introducing custom API endpoint (see example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89181/how-to-upload-a-file-attachment-to-custom-product-attribute-using-magento-soap/89741)).
However, this can be achieved with `multiCall`, which is available in SOAP V1 or XML RPC APIs, see [official dev docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAP).