# How to fetch store information with all attributes in magento api

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, api, soap-api-v2

I am stuck here for develop new API for stores information in Magento.

I'm trying to fetch store info from default API but it's not useful for me. I need all attributes what we have in admin like address, telephone, store images etc..

Please help me.

Comment: See this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89741/697 , it shows how to customize Magento API

Comment: yes, i know how to implement custom api module in magento, but here  need to fetch store all attributes(storeimage, latitude, longitude etc) instead of default result('store_id' ,'code' ,'website_id',  'group_id' ,'name', 'sort_order','is_active')

Comment: Can you share api name you are tried?